# OpenVPN connect to other servers in LAN

Tags: ubuntu, routing, openvpn, tunneling

I have installed OpenVPN on a Ubuntu server and I have OpenVPN -client on my PC.

I can connect from the client to the server with no problem (still have the same ip). How can I set up connection to all my other servers through the VPN?

Lets say I have server A, server B, VPN server, and client. How can I set a connection for the client to server A/B form the VPN tunnel?

Comment: If they're in the same lan, then with a correct routing table, maybe combined with NAT.
if ther're independent, then make one vpn connection to each.

Answer (score 0):

Normally all you need to do is ensure that the VPN server is the default gateway for the client when it is connected. You can do that by pushing

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

or perhaps

```
push "redirect-gateway local def1"
```

You really should  spend some time with the documentation or a HowTo or both. Try https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html